# How to print jqGrid (using jqPrint ?)

Tags: jquery, iframe, printing, jqgrid

I'm quite new to the jQuery world and I got a requirement which is "Print a web page which contains some data and a jqGrid table"

I found the jqPrint plugin which is "almost" what I was looking for. My problem is when I click on my print link, just the visible part of my jqGrid is printed, not every rows.

I've seen in some posts, that there's maybe an option to pass data to an iFrame without settings an height to the Grid and print like that, but I totally lack the skills to achieve that...

Is there some other ways to do that ? 
Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

There are no special printing features in jqGrid.

Look at this [Print webpages problems :: looking for good tutorial to print web pages (build by Jquery ui, jqgrid , zend)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2962142/print-webpages-problems-looking-for-good-tutorial-to-print-web-pages-build-by/2962569#2962569).